# What model types are supported by OpenScale?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

Does OpenScale support all types of model that can be deployed to Watson Machine Learning? Or just a subset of them?

Among the supported types of model, will the explainability feature work for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Only a subset of model types are supported **as of today**. 
[image]

**You can find the complete details/updates** [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/ai-openscale?topic=ai-openscale-in-ov#in-ov)

As shown above, Yes. the explainability is supported in all the supported models. Additionally, you can find the supported frameworks in the same link